# Accessing same map from cgroup skb ebpf and tc egress ebpf hook

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, trafficshaping

I am trying to access fmap which is already present in cgroup skb bpf object file, from tc egress ebpf hook.

By default, the map is getting created in /sys/fs/bpf/tc/globals/fmap. But i want to access the /sys/fs/bpf/fmap in tc egress cgroup. How to pass fmap path to tc program.

tc filter add dev  egress bpf object-file ./parse_simple.o section simple direct-action

```
struct flow
{

        __be32  saddr;

        __be32  daddr;

};

 
struct bpf_elf_map SEC("maps") fmap = { 

        .type       = BPF_MAP_TYPE_LRU_HASH,

        .size_key   = sizeof(struct flow),

        .size_value = sizeof(u32),

        .pinning    = PIN_GLOBAL_NS,

        .max_elem   = 100,

};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190723/ebpf-will-bpf-object-pin-maps-pin-internal-maps-for-bpf-map-type-hash-of-ma

Answer (score 1):

`libbpf bpf_map__pin()` can be used to set the pin path. So if I set the path as `PIN_GLOBAL_NS` (`/sys/fs/bpf/tc/globals`) in the `cgroup skb` loading program, `tc` is able to access the same map. But I don't know the reverse (access the map which is pinned in non `tc` base path [example: `/sys/fs/bpf/fmap`]).

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190723/ebpf-will-bpf-object-pin-maps-pin-internal-maps-for-bpf-map-type-hash-of-ma)